# Angular value binding sent to ng-click function instead of value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, binding

I have a link with handler in HTML:

```
<div class="menu-item" ng-repeat="pageName in pages">
    <a ng-click="routing.open('{{pageName}}')">{{pageName}}</a>
</div>
```

It triggers the '`open`' function in a self-made Angular-UI Routing Factory / helper and sends the '`pageName`' as param.
The open method checks if there's a handler or state for loading a view.

```
var availableStates = $state.get();
    if (!pages[name] || availableStates.indexOf(name) === -1) {
        alert("State or Loader for state: '{0}' does not exist!".format(name));
        return;
    }
```

When clicked the alert shows with this message:
[image]

But when I look in the web console, the value has been set properly.
[image]

I could use some help with this, what causes this behaviour and how does one fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You should not use {{ }} inside ng expressions. Replace

```
ng-click="routing.open('{{pageName}}')">
```

with

```
ng-click="routing.open(pageName)">
```

The reason for this is that you should consider all the specialized "ng-like" expressions as already enclosed in {{ }}, since they are already evaluated as angular expressions. You should only use {{ }} when you want to tell angular that you want the content enclosed on the double brackets to be evaluated as an angular expression.